# Observing Firebase Authenfication with ObservableObject

Tags: firebase-authentication, swiftui

I am trying to observe firebase authentification and update my View accordingly.

```
I have an SessionStore object:

    class SessionStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var session: Account?
    var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?


    deinit {
        stopListen()
    }

    func listen() {
        if handle == nil {
            handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
                if let user = user {
                    print("User logged in: \(user)")
                    self.session = Account.preData
                }  else {
                    self.session = nil
                }

            }
        }
    }

    func stopListen() {
        if let handle = handle {
            Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(handle)
        }
    }
}
```

I use it in a view like this:

```
    struct TabBarView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var sessionStore: SessionStore

    @State var selectedTab = Tab.swiping
    enum Tab: Int {
        case swiping, matches, profil
    }

    func getUser() {
        sessionStore.listen()
    }


    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if (sessionStore.session != nil) {
                         TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                            SwipingView().tabItem {
                                TabBarItem(text: "Text", image: "pause.circle")
                            }.tag(Tab.swiping)
                        }
                    } else {
                        LoginView()
                    }
        }.onAppear(perform: getUser).onDisappear(perform: sessionStore.stopListen)
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
sessionStore = SessionStore()
TabBarView().environmentObject(sessionStore!)
```

But it is only showing the LoginView even when the session is not nil. I made some code changes this is actually the solution.

Comment: You never stopListen() so why do you call multiple listen()?

Comment: thanks, that was only a copy paste error, from a version before but I got the solution now

Comment: You are still creating a new listener every time that view appears and never removing listeners.

Comment: thanks, I made some changes do you think that is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the way to do that

```
class SessionStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var session: Account?
```

Also you referenced `self` inside the state closure meaning your object will never deinit. Add unowned or weak like so:

```
handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { [unowned self] (auth, user) in
```

https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/weak-self/

Answer (score 0):

The correct implementation is:

```
class SessionStore: ObservableObject {
    let objectWillChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()
    var session: Account? {
        didSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
    var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?


    deinit {
        stopListen()
    }

    func listen() {
        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
            if let user = user {
                print("User logged in: \(user)")
                self.session = Account.preData
            }  else {
                self.session = nil
            }

        }
    }

    func stopListen() {
        if let handle = handle {
            Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(handle)
        }
    }
}
```

More info about it:
https://www.pointfree.co/blog/posts/30-swiftui-and-state-management-corrections